# Should I make single machine learning model for predicting price of house or 6 different models, given 6 datasets for different cities?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

I am currently working on ["Housing Prices in Metropolitan Areas of India"](https://www.kaggle.com/ruchi798/housing-prices-in-metropolitan-areas-of-india) (kaggle dataset), with 6 different csv files for 6 different cities.

All have same columns (40).

Working on a real estate website project, I am confused, should I make separate model for each csv or merge all csv to form one model (after data cleaning) to predict house prices.

Comment: You can do both

Comment: both can be done with varying degrees of success (based on problem at hand, datasets and algorithms used)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. @JayaramIyer

Comment: Thank you for the help @NikosM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options would work. It would depend on which method you want to use, what you want to do afterwards, or computing capacity.

E.g. developing a model for each city might allow you to contrast and compare the outcomes more simply. But you can also do multivariate predictions to predict for each city even once you have combined your dataset.

Also if your dataset is very large it might make sense to treat the cities independently to make the computations slightly cheaper.

Comment: Thank you, your advice was helpful  @WBM